# I need help in applying multi-threading to groovy class

Tags: multithreading, groovy, jira

I have one groovy class which creates issue but when I need create issue more than 2, I'm facing with performance problems that's why I would like to use threads for better performance.

Here is my code example. Please help me adding multi-threading to this code(I would like to apply mutli-threading to **static void main part**):

```
import // some libraries
class NotificationIssue
{
   NotificationIssue()
  {
  //Some codes
  }

  def getCustomFieldsValues (issueid)
  {
  //Some codes
  }

  def Check3cxPhone()
  {
  //Some codes
  }
  def CheckNetworkFolder()
  {
  //Some codes
  }

  def setIQLFacadeAndObjectFacade()
  {
  //Some codes
  }

  def CheckServerSystemAndUserAccount()
  {
   //Some codes
   }

  def CheckService()
  {
  //Some codes
  }

  def setIssueInputParameter()
  {
  //Some codes
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

//1st Notification issue for IT
NotificationIssue NotificationForIT = new NotificationIssue()
def key1 = NotificationForIT.getCustomFieldsValues(issue.key)
NotificationForIT.setIQLFacadeAndObjectFacade()
NotificationForIT.Check3cxPhone()
NotificationForIT.CheckNetworkFolder()
NotificationForIT.CheckServerSystemAndUserAccount()
NotificationForIT.CheckService()
NotificationForIT.setIssueInputParameter(customerRtype, "Notification Issue-", issueType, user,"SD",10200)

//2nd Notification for another department
NotificationIssue StampNotification = new NotificationIssue()
def key2 = StampNotification.getCustomFieldsValues(issue.key)
StampNotification.setIQLFacadeAndObjectFacade()


//3rd Notification issue for...
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did it using thread.start() and thread.join()